# Best Practice for a .net form after submitting to a database

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am wanting to know what is best practice when submitting a form using .net.

I have a simple contact form consisting of Name, Email, Comments and a submit button - on submit I would am submitting the data to a database and want to display a message to the user that this has been successfully. I have done this a couple of times but would like to know what is best practice for this?

1. Response.Redirect("~/samepage.aspx");
2. Response.Redirect("~/Thankyoupage.aspx")
3. Using Panels - On submit Panel1.Visibility = false, Panel2.Visibility = true;
4. Or any other

I want it so when the user presses the back button in the browser the form isnt populated still, as at the moment when I go back I can keep submitting the same data over and over again.

There seems to be lots of different ways but I want to know what is best practice.

Thanks

Comment: that is up to you and your requirements.

Comment: We can help with questions about the technical implementation.  But for questions about the user experience itself, you might check with the UX Stack Exchange site.  Take a look at their help center first though, I can't really speak to exactly what is considered on-topic there or where they draw the line on opinion-based questions.

Comment: Thanks you - If I was to change the question to - How to prevent the form from allowing resubmission after submitting. I know something when you are on a site and submit and when you try to go back you get the pop up /alert box saying you are unable to reload or something?

Comment: In case of error, stay on the same page and display error. In case of success, redirect to another page. It's the best practice to track navigation (eg for analytics)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle the form submissions.

If you dont want the textboxes to retain the value when you press the back button on the browser you should set the `EnableViewState`to `False` for all the textboxes.

Comment: I have just changed the text boxes enableviewstate to false but after submission I can select the back button and they are retaining the values still

Comment: Set the `EnableViewState` to `False` for the entire page

Comment: that doesnt seem to have worked either... I am still able to click the back button in the browser and see the values in the textboxes?